# cross-site asp.net query string

Tags: asp.net, string

I am implementing as asp.net website to act as a multi language website template that I am going to use in future developments. I am using a query string to indicate what language to display and by default the url looks like this: www.site.com/default.aspx?lnag=en where English is the default language.

In my master page I have an html menu that looks like this:

```
<ul>
            <li><a href="../../Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../../About.aspx">About</a></li>  
        </ul>
```

Notice that when the user clicks on the "About" link, it will, obviously, loses the query string and it will transfer the user to www.site.com/About.aspx .

Now, I want the query string (lnag) to stay there on ALL page links/URLs and redirects without having to manually adding the query string for each and every link on my site. I already have a page base class but I am not sure how/where I am suppose to capture/insert the query string for the requested/responded page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then edit your question and correct it.

Comment: Still no vote for the Answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use following code

```
var lang = 'en';
$('a').attr('href', function() { return this+ '?'+ lang });
```

Comment: Yes -- another good reason to store the language in the cookie rather than the session. You can access cookie from script.

Answer (score 1):

Store the language in a [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.session.aspx) variable - update it only if it exists on the URL and if it doesn't, use what's in the `Session` variable (with some sane default).

Comment: SEO ...  I want ALL my pages to be SEO-friendly and visible by search engines in all supported languages

Comment: @ealshabaan - And? How is this making that not happen?

Comment: Take for example, google.com. I believe their search engine does not capture any information about sessions used in the crawled website. So if Google crawler visit my website on www.site.com/defult.aspx?lang=en , then all the content is going to be indexed in English including site.com/about.aspx. Another case is if Google crawled my website using site.com/default.aspx?lang=ar then all the content is going to be indexed in Arabic including site.com/about.aspx . do you see the problem in about.aspx?! the language of about.aspx content depends on the sessions which Google cannot detect.

Comment: So even though Google may save the about.aspx page as an Arabic content page, it will be displayed in English when the user visit the link directly without passing through the default.aspx/?lang=ar first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to SEO your site, I would suggest not putting the language in the querystring. It really belongs in the URL. For example:

http://www.site.com/en/content

instead of

http://www.site.com/content?lang=en

You should be able to accomplish this using UrlRewriting (since you are using ASP.NET webforms). However, it is much easier to do in ASP.NET MVC with their Routing pattern.

The only other thing I have to add is, store the language in the cookie rather than the session. This way, if the user changes their language, and returns to the site (starting a new session), their favorite language is remembered.

Comment: I have actually tried to use asp.net routing but I got stocked somewhere and that's why i shifted to query string. 
But I know that a clean urls are better for SEO.